# C# compiler creates ref class

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I was digging through some code, when suddenly a wild bug appeared...

Ok let's start.
I created this code to represent a position in a script while parsing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a position in script. (Used for error reporting)
/// </summary>
public sealed class Position
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Line count.
    /// </summary>
    public int Line { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Character count.
    /// </summary>
    public int Char { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Index data.
    /// </summary>
    public int Index { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize new Position object to standard values.
    /// </summary>
    public Position()
    {
        this.Line = 1;
        this.Char = 1;
        this.Index = 0;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy a Position object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pos"></param>
    public Position(Position pos)
    {
        this.Line = pos.Line;
        this.Char = pos.Char;
        this.Index = pos.Index;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize new Position object to given parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p_index">The index in stream.</param>
    /// <param name="p_line">The line count.</param>
    /// <param name="p_char">The character count</param>
    public Position(int p_index, int p_line, int p_char)
    {
        this.Line = p_line;
        this.Char = p_char;
        this.Index = p_index;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if 2 Position objects are equal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p1">Left operand.</param>
    /// <param name="p2">Right operand.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true, if both position objects are equal.</returns>
    public static Boolean operator ==(Position p1, Position p2)
    {
        return
            p1.Index == p2.Index &&
            p1.Char == p2.Char &&
            p1.Line == p2.Line;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if 2 Position objects are not equal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p1">Left operand.</param>
    /// <param name="p2">Right operand.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Boolean operator !=(Position p1, Position p2)
    {
        return !(p1 == p2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Equals overload.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Position)
            return this == (Position)obj;
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ToString override.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", this.Index, this.Line, this.Char);
    }
}
```

But... When I do something like this:

```
var pos1 = new Position();
var pos2 = pos1;
pos2.Char = 10;
```

Then I change the value of pos1.Char too... I don't know this behavior from C#. The other classes behave the same.

The copy constructor did not help.

I use .NET 4.5 and VS 2012 Update 3...

Can someone tell me what causes this behavior? Or atleast how to get arround this behavior...

Comment: It's just a reference Type.

Comment: It is the expected behavior. Classes are called "reference types" for a reason...

Answer (score 3):

`pos1` is a reference to the new object. By setting `pos2` to `pos1`, you now have two references to the same object. If you want two different objects, you should do

```
var pos1 = new Position();  // Create a new object
var pos2 = new Position(pos1);  // Use your copy constructor
pos2.Char = 10;
```

Comment: This did not help. I test it now again.

Answer (score 1):

Your ´Position´ class is a ´reference type´
When you equal pos2 to pos1 it points to the same memory location.

Changing the property of one object will thus change the other one also as it is the same object

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug; this is correct C# behavior. `Position` is a `class`, which is a reference type. The assignment `var pos2 = pos1;` doesn't copy anything, it just creates another reference to the same `Position` instance.

You want to call your copy constructor like this:

```
var pos2 = new Position(pos1);
```